# Is there a way to restrict locked cells in excel running multiple macros?

Tags: excel

I need assistance with using macros on a protected sheet.

I am new to Excel code and have created one macro.  However, in the excel sheet I want only certain cells to be editable.  The entire sheet has locked cells except for the ones I want locked.  However, after I protect the sheet, my one macro no longer works.  I need help.   Below is the one macro I have, I just need another one to allow the unlocked cells to still run the macro.

This is the one macro I have, which does work...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address(False, False) = "B27" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "None": Rows("28:44").Hidden = True
        Case "Custom Packaging": Rows("29:35").Hidden = True: Rows("36:39").Hidden = False: Rows("40:44").Hidden = False
        Case "Stock Packaging": Rows("29:35").Hidden = False: Rows("36:39").Hidden = True: Rows("40:44").Hidden = False
    End Select
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can unlock the worksheet with a macro, then re-lock it after. This is usually what I've seen other macros involving locked sheets do. You can google to find some code that'll do that for you

Answer (score 0):

As @Selkie said, just unlock/lock the worksheet as needed:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address(False, False) = "B27" Then

        ActiveSheet.Unprotect "mypassword"

        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "None": Rows("28:44").Hidden = True
            Case "Custom Packaging": Rows("29:35").Hidden = True: Rows("36:39").Hidden = False: Rows("40:44").Hidden = False
            Case "Stock Packaging": Rows("29:35").Hidden = False: Rows("36:39").Hidden = True: Rows("40:44").Hidden = False
        End Select

        ActiveSheet.Protect "mypassword"

    End If

End Sub
```